# Is Elon Musk's child name valid in California?

Tags: united-states, california, children, name

Elon Musk and his partner want to name their child *X Æ A-12*.

Is that name allowed in California, US?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107859/discussion-on-question-by-gsamaras-is-elon-musks-child-name-valid-in-california).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

We could start with what the statutes say ([HSC 102425](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=HSC&division=102.&title=&part=1.&chapter=3.&article=2.))

> (a) The certificate of live birth for a live birth occurring on or
> after January 1, 2016, shall contain those items necessary to
> establish the fact of the birth and shall contain only the following
> information; (1) Full name and sex of the child.

It says nothing about the form of that name. Therefore, any prohibition of the letter Æ (or æ) etc. would have to come from the administrative interpretation of California Department of Public Health, Vital Records. There is a [long handbook](http://www.avss.ucsb.edu/MANUALS/Handbook.pdf), which on p. 112 states the rule regarding child names. The rules note that

> The form must be completed using the 26 alphabetical characters of the
> English language with appropriate punctuation, if necessary.
>
> No pictographs (☺), ideograms (⇑), diacritical marks (è, ñ, ē, ç), or
> extraneous entries are allowed.

So the short answer is, unless you feel like making a court case out of the matter and you have a lot of money, this name will not be allowed. The rule might be challenged in court as exceeding statutory authority, and might well be deemed to discriminate w.r.t. race and national origin. The rule could be defended on grounds of necessity, if we presume that the department is incapable of recording information other than the 26 letters and "appropriate punctuation" (undefined, presumably only apostrophe). It's not that in principle Unicode doesn't exist, it's that their system may not be capable of dealing with it (numerous problems would arise from the non-unique mapping from visual representation to Unicode number). There does not seem to be a court ruling on the matter.

Comment: ["X AE A-TWELVE" should be legal.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/51365/is-elon-musks-child-name-valid-in-california#comment102581_51366) reminds me of the story about [1069](https://apnews.com/5983f73686a6ace6421bc2a0340064a5) . Legally denied  in MN, MI, ND.

Comment: Hyphens are no doubt also 'appropriate punctuation'. I know several Californians who spell their given name with a hyphen.

Comment: The fact that the form itself limits the kind of input involved in the name does not per se me that the name is not allowed, it is simply a limitation on how the name may be described on a particular government form for purposes of a particular government document. It is not necessarily a person's "true name" for all purposes.

Comment: For God sake, I cannot believe this story.... In Spain the law bans to name a child with names that can cause suffering or discrimination because of that. You cannot name your children "stupid" or something like that, it's forbidden to keep the welfare of the children. T

Comment: It might open the law up to all sorts of interpretation issues, but I find "diacritical marks" being forbidden to ridiculous (at very least). I don't have those marks in my name, but I know those that do. It's not their name with the English language equivalent letters. It's 2020 - are they using a typewriter to enter these?

Comment: @RaulLuna So it is illegal to call your child Janus in Spain. I knew a kid in primary school that was tortured to the extreme by the other children because of the body part his name rhymed with.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: no, it is not illegal. In Spain you can call your son Janus and it is not a problem. Or other names that have funny rhymes, even in Spanish. But it's illegal call your son Anus. Or Vagina.